# How to make condition inside return of map function in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary

How to repeat below the block of code using map function in `react.js`? I want to repeat the block of code having `class specialties_check_list` inside `div` having `class specialties_check_outer`.

```
<div class="specialties_check_outer">
<div class="specialties_check_list">
    <div class="left_side">
        <div class="experience_type">
            <p><label class="check_boxes"><input type="checkbox"><span class="checkmark"></span></label><span class="label_name">AR/VR</span></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="right_side">
        <div class="experience_type">
            <p><label class="check_boxes"><input type="checkbox"><span class="checkmark"></span></label><span class="label_name">Backend</span></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="specialties_check_list">
    <div class="left_side">
        <div class="experience_type">
            <p><label class="check_boxes"><input type="checkbox"><span class="checkmark"></span></label><span class="label_name">Computer Vision</span></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="right_side">
        <div class="experience_type">
            <p><label class="check_boxes"><input type="checkbox"><span class="checkmark"></span></label><span class="label_name">Data</span></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="specialties_check_list">
    <div class="left_side">
        <div class="experience_type">
            <p><label class="check_boxes"><input type="checkbox"><span class="checkmark"></span></label><span class="label_name">Frontend</span></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="right_side">
        <div class="experience_type">
            <p><label class="check_boxes"><input type="checkbox"><span class="checkmark"></span></label><span class="label_name">Full Stack</span></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       // Child component which will return the list of inner content

        const myList = (<props if you want to send any>) => (  <div class="specialties_check_list">   
                <div class="left_side">
                    <div class="experience_type">
                        <p><label class="check_boxes"><input type="checkbox"><span class="checkmark"></span></label><span class="label_name">AR/VR</span></p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="right_side">
                    <div class="experience_type">
                        <p><label class="check_boxes"><input type="checkbox"><span class="checkmark"></span></label><span class="label_name">Backend</span></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> )    


     // Main class
         render() {

            return (
//Assuming you have put the data in state
            <div class="specialties_check_outer">
                { this.state.data.map((item, index) =>  ( <myList /> ))}  
            </div>
            )

            }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but i have to repeat left_side and right_side blocks in iteration. Means in one iteration <div class="specialties_check_list"><div class="left_side"></div></div> and in second iteration it will become like <div class="specialties_check_list"><div class="left_side"></div><div class="right_side"></div></div> and so on..